# QGIS: interpolate difference in Z-value on enbankments

Tags: qgis, hydrography, z-value

I have two layers:

- 1 polygon layer with a theoretical profile of a harbour.
- 1 pointlayer with output from my multibeam echousounder.

I made a new pointlayer with a Z-difference between the two layers.
The output is a value above or under the theoretical profile by comparing the Z from a point to the Z from the theoretical profile using [geomwithin]

this is the result chart:
[image: screenshot]

The red spots are above the theoretical profile, the green spots under the theoretical profile.

Here is my problem.

The blue lines are the outlines of the polygons. I'm good with the polygons that have only 1 value (the flat areas in the theoretical profile), but I have a problem with sloped embankments.

The provider of the theoretical profile put a min and max z value in the data. But it is not specified in a way that I can use it.

My goal:

Make a chart that also calculates the embankments (the slopes) Z-difference, instead of the current method where the slopes are only compared to 1 value.

[image: whiteboard]
I would like to calculate the green areas.

Am I in the right direction in thinking:

- I need to add the right Z-value to the vertices of the polygon of the theoretical profile
- I need a method to interpolate between the vertices with a minimal and maximum Z-value of the theoretical profile.
- I need a method to compare the measured Z-value and the interpolated Z of the slopes.

I would like some advice on the validity of my method. and some guidance in how to interpolate or make a 3D version of the theoretical profile.

Comment: This type of calculation is usually done in raster format. My approach would be to convert the elevation polygons to a raster. Zooming in on the elevation polygons, it actually looks like they're made up of little boxes, which makes me think it was originally a raster layer that was converted to polygons using a tool like `polygonize (vector to raster)`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "min and max z value" that you aren't able to use - are those in the attribute table?

Comment: @csk the measured data is a pointlayer 1x1grid. The min Max values are in the otherlayer in the attribute table